# how to Access google play account?

Tags: node.js

hello~ I made authentication server with nodejs.

one. facebook authentication :

```
var options = {
        host: 'graph.facebook.com',
        port: 443,
        path: apiPath + '&access_token=' + accessToken,
        method: 'GET'
    };

var request = https.get(options, function(result){
        result.setEncoding('utf8');
        result.on('data', function(chunk){
            buffer += chunk;
        });
```

two. Google play authentication :

I did not find the 'graph.facebook.com 'like google play page

how to make google play authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this article:
http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/06/node-and-google-oauth/

And here is a simple example:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/oauth2.js

more information you can find in google node.js client in git hub:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/